# How to find the area between two arcs and a line

Tags: integration, geometry, derivatives, analytic-geometry, area

Given curve C defined by the equations $x=3t^2,y=2t^3$ where $t$ is a parameter and line e which is tangent to C at point P where $t=2$, find the area $R$ between $C$ and $e$.

For this question I have worked out that $y=2x-8$ is the line $e$ by taking the derivative of $C$ and that the line $e$ intersects $C$ at a second point $Q(3,-2)$. However I can't work out how to find the area of $R$. I assume that it is with integrals, but I am stuck. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: You are finding area between $y = 2x - 8$ and $y^{2}=\frac{4x^{3}}{27}$. Did you sketch? Do you know how to find area using integral?

Comment: @MathLover Yes I know how to find the area using integral when it is between the curve and the x axis not when there is a line there as well

Comment: ok. you find value of $x$ in terms of $y$ from both equations and subtract. Line is to the right of the curve. That is the length of each horizontal strips. Now integrate that wrt $y$ between $y=-2$ and $y = 16$.

Comment: @MathLover I haven't understood your train of thought, could you please write it out mathematically?

Comment: If you look at the sketch, for any given $y$ in the region, $x$ is bound between the given curve and the line. The lower bound of $x$ is on the curve and upper bound is on the line.

Comment: So the integral should be $\displaystyle \int_{-2}^{16} [(y+8)/2 - (27y^2 / 4)^{1/3}] \ dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(2)=3(2)^2=12$$
$$y(2)=2(2)^3=16$$
so: $P=(12,16)$

Now:
$$x'(t)=6t,y'(t)=6t^2$$
so:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6(2)^2}{6(2)}=2$$
then you have:
$$(y-16)=2(x-12)$$
$$(e):y=2x-8$$
so that part is all good, and the second point is in fact $Q=(3,-2)$ now for $C$ try and get $y$ in terms of $x$